# How to add auto incrementing field in MongoDB aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to add an additional key number which holds a value of the auto-incrementing number. How can I achieve this? Below is the query. Is it possible to achieve this result without doing unwind and group?

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "iContestId":"5e4118161a7b5765ee9b40ef"
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "_id":"$_id",
         "nPointsEarned":"$nPointsEarned",
         "iContestId":"$iContestId",
         "iUserId":"$iUserId",
         "ranking":"$ranking",
         "sFullName":"$sFullName",
         "sProfilePicture":"$sImage",
         "nAutoIncrement": {
             "$count": {
                 "$sum": 1
             }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "ranking":1
      }
   },
   {
      "$skip":0
   },
   {
      "$limit":23
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. There is no any operator to generate the sequence number

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this now with the [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) operation (new as of Mongo 5) in the aggregation pipeline.

Something like:

```
Model
  .aggregate([
    { $match: queryFilter },
    {
      $setWindowFields: {
        sortBy: sortFilter,
        output: {
          yourIndexFieldName: {
            $count: {},
            window: { documents: ['unbounded', 'current'] },
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

will store each document (auto incrementing) index from the query in the `yourIndexFieldName` field.

This is because this will return the count of documents that match the filter specified by `queryFilter` relative to where the document exists within the window of documents.

So if the operation is looking at document 4 in the window, the count up to that point in the window of documents will be 4.

Note: Because of the nature of `$count`, indexing will start at 1 and not 0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of `$addFields` and `$add` (supported in v5 and up).

```js
Model.updateMany({ iContestId: '5e4118161a7b5765ee9b40ef' }, [
  {
    $addFields: {
      nAutoIncrement: { $add: ['$nAutoIncrement', 1] },
    },
  }
]);
```

If `nAutoIncrement` is an existing field in your collection then it'll get 1 added to it. If it's not I think this will add that field to the document (don't quote me on that).

Check out mongodb docs on [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).