# I want to update multi document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections

I have a collection in mongoDB that hold 66000 documents on it, Now I want to add new filed to all theses document a uniqueID field which take this form S-1111 and the number increase for the next document

I have tried to make a call to DB and update each one in order but it take to much time because this is a lot of request to mongoDB , so is there is another way to do that fast

I am working with Node and mongoose

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423945/13464279) it seems impossible autoincrement your desired `uniqueID` field.

Comment: I don't want it to be auto I have created a function to do that